# How do I enable autocompletion for windows users?

Tags: python, windows, python-click

I implemented a CLI tool using click and it has a way for linux users to have autocompletion as it's nicely documented. Basically one adds `source $(_FOO_COMPLETE=bash_source foo)` to `~/.bashrc`

Now, one of my colleagues uses my CLI tool from a VSCode powershell in windows and I have no clue how to allow him to have autocompletion. Anybody can help here?

I tried to source the script from the powershell, but it returns `'_FOO_COMPLETE=bash_source' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file or operable program`